# Is there a tool for automatically converting filter implementation forms?

Tags: filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

I am looking for alternate tools that will automatically convert filter implementation forms (or signal flow network diagrams in general) to simplest or alternate forms; for example for going between direct form I, direct form II, transpose, ladder, etc...

I am familiar with "convert" in Matlab; but for that function you need to specify the forms. I would prefer one that would quickly generate all options, or provide more intelligence in simplifying the network, so seeing what other options might be out there.

Is this something that is readily available in Octave, or Python- or some other open source solution?

Comment: Now since there are no answers yet, I would like to ask a new question instead. Why do yo need an **automatic** tool for doing that conversion? What's the potential benefit? I assume that for the most of the basic filters the conversion (if possible) can be done on paper (guided with a few line of computational code if necessary). I cannot see the true benefit of using automated version of that instead...

Comment: Yes for basic filters it would be simple to just do on paper; I am envisioning more complex structures and would imagine such a tool that could immediately present all options would be useful. I have done some very interesting simplifications and reductions from rearranging filter structures but it usually takes me a few iterations to get there.